# To prove two matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\overline A$ denotes the conjugate of the matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Prove $\overline AA$ is similar to $A\overline A$.

I am reviewing my summer homework. I have a proof but it is long, so I posted this question to seek some more straightforward approaches. My idea is to show $\overline AA$ and $A\overline A$ have the same Jordan blocks.

Comment: Hello, Falang. Please see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) about how to ask for help with homework problems.

Comment: My apologies. I am reviewing my summer homework. I have a proof but it is long, so I posted this question to seek some more straightforward approaches. My idea is to show $\overline AA$ and $A\overline A$ have the same Jordan blocks.

Comment: What is the field ?

Comment: @Belgi Most likely $\mathbb{C}$ since there are conjugate matrices.

Comment: Yes, I mean $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: I don't know if it's an entirely vacuous observation that in the invertible case, $A(\overline A A)A^{-1} = A\overline A$...

Comment: But we dont know whether $A$ is nonsingular or not.

Comment: Is there a transpose as well as conjugate ?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is working, but is not so easy to put it in practice. Maybe [this reference](http://books.google.ro/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=%22AA+is+similar+to+AA%22&source=bl&ots=mt0uHqTTG6&sig=wVDk6GK-qU1sQlFzIjJ5EOfVIXk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GTIiUsiWGuSd7QbO5oDgCQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22AA%20is%20similar%20to%20AA%22&f=true) can help you.